# I am trying click button feature where user can download file directly from the UI

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, axios

I have a url ,which can be accessed to download files after providing username and password.
My frontend is in React and a backend server running on flask.
I have a button on frontend when on clicked ,it prompts for the credentials ,after that axios request is sent to the url to download the file.

```
var config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://10.106.76.50/logcollection/1/log',
        headers: {
            Authorization: basicAuth,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },

        crossdomain: true,
    };

    axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

But it returns with CORS error everytime.
When trying the same request from the flask server it is successful

```
url = "https://10.106.76.50/logcollection/1/log"
requests.request("GET", url,auth=credentials,verify=False,timeout=5)
```

Now I have to do two step process where the file is saved on my server and then I request for that file from frontend.
Is there a way the flask can redirect the file to axios without saving it ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue via the [flask-cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) plugin

`$ pip install flask-cors`

A simple demo:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/")
def helloWorld():
  return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"
```

The [docs](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)